# ReferenceInput not properly populating SelectInput

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I'm using react-admin v3.15 (because reasons). I am trying to create a simple Create form that populates a dropdown with values from a resource. For some reason I have a one dropdown that works and another that does not. They call different APIs but they literally return similar things. What are some things that might be implicitly known that I have to watch out for that might cause this?

```
export const CreateFormTest = () => {
    return (
        <SimpleForm>
            <ReferenceInput
                label="Foo 1"
                source="foo1"                
                reference="foo1"                
                fullWidth
            >
                <SelectInput optionText="value" />
            </ReferenceInput>
            <ReferenceInput
                label="Foo 2"
                source="foo2"                
                reference="itemResource"                
                fullWidth
            >
                <SelectInput optionText="value" />
            </ReferenceInput>
        </SimpleForm>
    );
}
```

I've checked the network calls and they literally return the same headers, body, etc. The resource are there too. There is a dataProvider function that manipulates the request / response but nothing that should affect the working endpoint specifically.

Any help / hints or common things to look out for when doing this would be appreciated.

Comment: Without knowing more and based on the docs I might double check that your source and reference refer to the correct record and fields? I get that your example code is contrived but for example checking that `foo2` has field `itemResource` and `foo1` has field `foo1` and those reference the correct records. No mixup with source and reference in your markup? I haven't used this library but figured I'd give it a shot in case it was just something simple like that.

Comment: In what way does one of them not work? Does the field appear, but with no select values?

Comment: Oh, yes. The API response is correct, but no select values appear.